# GRUB2 Boot Configuration

Tags: grub, fedora-12

Recently i installed GRUB2, everything is working fine. When my system is started my monitor is showing something like the following

> "Minimal BASH-Like line editing is
>   supported. For the first word, TAB
>   lists possible command completions.
>   Anywhere else TAB lists the possible
>   completions of a device/filename."
>
> Press "Esc" key to enter the menu. Boot windows...

and when i press the Esc key it then shows the GRUB2 menu showing list of operating systems installed on my system

How the remove "Minimal BASH-Like line editing ...." text. I only need this line

> Press "Esc" key to enter the menu.
>   Boot windows...

Note: Both my WindowsXP and Fedora12 are working fine and loading with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not something configurable in the GRUB configuration files.  You would need to recompile GRUB2.  This string is defined in [normal/main.c](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-core-dev/ubuntu/lucid/grub2/lucid/annotate/head%3A/normal/main.c) (the **msg** variable; see line 539 in the Ubuntu version; the Fedora version should be near but may not be on exactly the same line).  Altering it **might** be as simple as changing that line and recompiling.

I highly recommend creating your own RPM package(s) with your modified source.  That way you can still use your package manager to handle updates.  See for example [Packaging software with RPM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1/).